# Delete output plots in shiny

Tags: shiny

I am trying to initialize output plots in shiny when button is clicked, meaning output plots will be deleted from the screen when button is pressed, but I don't know the exact command for that. I tried something like:

```
observedEvent(input$button, { output$plot1 <- NULL })
```

but it doesn't work. 
Hope you can help,

Thanks

Comment: A simple workaroud is to put an empty plot ``observedEvent(input$button, { output$plot1 <- ggplot() })`` but you can see a grey square

Answer (score 3):

Instead of deleting the plot, you can either `show` or `hide` it with `shinyjs`

```
rm(list=ls())
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  sidebarPanel(actionButton("button", "Hide Plot1"),
               actionButton("button2", "Show Plot1"),br(),
               actionButton("button3", "Hide Plot2"),
               actionButton("button4", "Show Plot2")),
  mainPanel(plotOutput("plot1"),plotOutput("plot2"))
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$button, {
    hide("plot1")
  })
  observeEvent(input$button2, {
    show("plot1")
  })
  observeEvent(input$button3, {
    hide("plot2")
  })
  observeEvent(input$button4, {
    show("plot2")
  })

  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
    hist(mtcars$mpg)
  })
  output$plot2 <- renderPlot({
    hist(mtcars$qsec)
  })

}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```